# Using a static std::map<int,MyClass*> inside MyClass causes unresolve external symbol

Tags: c++

I want to keep track of the instance of `MyClass`, so I have add a private static variable `std::map<int,MyClass*>` inside MyClass. The problem now is it causes unresolved external symbol, which I don't know how to debug. How can I resolve this?

Note: I'm a seasoned Java programmer and novice C++ programmer, and also I'll be using this as a `JNI` `dll`, that is why I need to keep track the instances of `MyClass`.

Comment: There is no need to comment your note.. Don't worry, it'll compile ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably haven't provided the implementation:

MyClass.h:

```
class MyClass {
private:
    static std::map<int, MyClass *> m_instances;
...
};
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

// Add this
std::map<int, MyClass *> MyClass::m_instances;
```

Comment: Can't accept answer in 6mins. :P
This is the right answer. Thanks for providing it.